# testing UI for android app

Tags: android, testing, user-interface

I have an application which now is on google play. Ther developement and testing have been made on a Samsung Galaxy 9100.

Now I'll like to test my application on some virtual devices, but i didn;t find any article about whoch are the common displays between android phones.

Can you tell me which resolutions need the virtual devices to have? Can you point me to a blog, tutorial, article about this topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Support Multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) is very useful, please read it first. but if you want short answer

set AVD setting for most compatible low resolution smartphones 240x320

- Target: Android 2.1 - API Level 7
- Skin: QVGA
- Hardware: Abstracted LCD density 120

set AVD setting for medium resolution smartphones 320x480

- Target: Android 2.1 - API Level 7
- Skin: HVGA
- Hardware: Abstracted LCD density 160

set AVD setting for high resolution smartphones 480x800

- Target: Android 2.1 - API Level 7
- Skin: WVGA800
- Hardware: Abstracted LCD density 240

set AVD setting for medium dpi resolution for tablets! ( smartphone! ) like galaxy tab 7

- Target: Android 2.1 - API Level 7
- Skin: WVGA854
- Hardware: Abstracted LCD density 160

set AVD setting for high resolution tablets

- Target: Android 3.0 - API Level 11
- Skin: WXGA
- Hardware: Abstracted LCD density 160

Answer (score 3):

there are many web services which provide access to virtual android devices you can test your app on

1. http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/android.html
2. http://www.deviceready.com/
3. https://www.lesspainful.com/
4. http://www.youwave.com/

also there is android for x86 and many other web platforms which you can test your app on.

Samsung also have an interface where you can test your app on.

Comment: can you give me some details about the samsung option oin which you can test my interface?

Answer (score 3):

In case if you want to create several AVDs and test your app locally, Google provide an official dev guide [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Worth to read through if you have not done yet.

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a good read on this official dedicated page for this topic:

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html